# reading back a float number

Tags: c, casting, eeprom, mplab-c18

I am using microchip c18 and i have this function which splits the float in to 4 respective bytes.And C18 follow little endianess

```
a[0]=*(fptr);        address 0
a[1]=*(fptr+1);              1  
a[2]=*(fptr+2);              2    
a[3]=*(fptr+3);              3
```

and writes in to serial eeprom.

If i wanted to read back the float variable.

```
float read_float(void)
{   float f;
    unsigned char *fptr;
    fptr=&f;

    *(fptr)=eepromread(0);
    *(fptr+1)=eepromread(1);
    *(fptr+2)=eepromread(2);
    *(fptr+3)=eepromread(3);      

    return(f);       
}
```

Will this function return the float variable?.
I'm devoid of any hardware and simulation tools right now.

I trust I'm clear on my question.
edit:

While doing so. a compiler mismatch error occurs on assigning char to float..How could i remove the error?

Comment: `(*fptr+2)` and `(*fptr+3)` look wrong to me.

Comment: oops.Thank you @suspectus.Newbie  here.So *(fptr) is the correct way right

Comment: it wouldn't be difficult to write a unit test for this by mocking eepromread

Comment: yes I believe so: `*(fptr+2)`

Comment: Type mismatch  error do occurs while doing so.I think assigning 'char'  *fptr to 'float' &f has been a problem and compiler does invokes an error signal

Comment: `*(fptr+2)` and `*fptr+2` are very different things, decide which one you want and stick to it

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is `*(char*)(fptr+`i`) = eepromread(`i`);`.  You want the offset from the initial pointer, cast to a pointer to a character, dereferenced.

Also, at least my compiler (gcc) balks at that first assignment.  You need something more like `fptr = (char*)(&f);` so that the pointer to the float is assignment-compatible.

Double-check, though, to be sure that `eepromread()` gives you the bytes in the order that you expect them.  They should, since IEEE754 is independent of byte-ordering, but the number of "clever enhancements" hidden in embedded C libraries could fill a pretty big book.

Comment: `fptr` is `unsigned char *`, I don't see what you gain by casting it to `char *`